# Android Studio 2.2 custom button

Tags: android, button

How do I add custom button in Android Studio 2.2?
I found info that I have to:

> make an .xml file in app/src/main/res/drawable (for example custom_button.xml):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:drawable="@drawable/button_on"
    android:state_pressed="true" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/button_focused"
    android:state_focused="true" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/button_off" />
</selector>
```

> add my .png images (button_on, button_off, button_focused) to app/src/main/res/drawable-xxhdpi (I do not have this folder - I placed images in drawable folder - making xxhdpi folder by myself and placing images there doesn't work either)
>
> edit activity_main.xml:

```
 <Button
        android:text=""
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/button_microphone"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/button_add_resource"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button_add_resource"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:background="@drawable/custom_button"/>
```

And now what? It doesn't work, although the button shows up in activity_main.xml visualiser.

Errors:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Solved.
I just forgot to use Android\sdk\tools\sdraw9patch.bat to make 1 pixel width borders on my images.